# what is a good way to remove last few directory

Tags: c#, .net

I need to parse a directory string I get and remove last few folders.

For example, when I have this directory string:

```
C:\workspace\AccurevTestStream\ComponentB\include
```

I may need to cut the last two directores to create a new directory string:

```
C:\workspace\AccurevTestStream
```

what is a good way to do this? I know I can use string `split` and `join` but I think there may be a better way to do this.

Comment: How will you decide how many to remove? Is it predetermined?

Comment: As it's variable I'd be tempted to go with `split` and `join`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a simple recursive method that assumes you know how many parent directories to remove from the path:

```
public string GetParentDirectory(string path, int parentCount) {
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(path) || parentCount < 1)
        return path;

    string parent = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path);

    if(--parentCount > 0)
        return GetParentDirectory(parent, parentCount);

    return parent;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

```
var path = "C:\workspace\AccurevTestStream\ComponentB\include";    
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(path);
var result = d.Parent.Parent.FullName;
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [`System.IO.Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) class in this case - if you call [`Path.GetDirectoryName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx) repeatedly, it will chop off the last path:

```
string path = @"C:\workspace\AccurevTestStream\ComponentB\include";
path = Path.GetDirectoryName(path); //returns C:\workspace\AccurevTestStream\ComponentB
path = Path.GetDirectoryName(path); //returns C:\workspace\AccurevTestStream
//etc
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try:

```
myNewString = myOriginalString.SubString(0, LastIndexOf(@"\"));
myNewString = myNewString.SubString(0, LastIndexOf(@"\"));
```

Not elegant, but should be effective.

**Edit:** (even more inelegant)

```
string myNewString = myOriginalString;
for(i=0;i<NumberToChop;i++)
{
    if(LastIndexOf(@"\") > 0)
        myNewString = myNewString.SubString(0, LastIndexOf(@"\"));
}
```

Comment: no, not the last, I need to cut one, two or more directories.

Comment: @5YrsLaterDBA - Added even more inelegant solution. Can be dropped into a method, turned into an extension, whatevs.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with the DirectoryInfo class and its Parent property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
    static String GoUp(String path, Int32 num)
    {
        if (num-- > 0)
        {
            return GoUp(Directory.GetParent(path).ToString(), num);
        }
        return path;
    }
```

Comment: [Same as mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389775/what-is-a-good-way-to-remove-last-few-directory/4389856#4389856), pretty much.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this:

```
string path = @"C:\workspace\AccurevTestStream\ComponentB\include"
string newPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(path, @"..\..\"));
```

**Note** This goes two levels up. The result would be:
    `newPath = @"C:\workspace\AccurevTestStream\";`

Answer (score -1):

What about this (sorry, I don't know what your criteria is for determining what to delete)...

```
var di = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\workspace\AccurevTestStream\ComponentB\include");
while (!deleteDir)
    di = di.Parent;
di.Delete(true);
```

Comment: I don't think he intends to delete the directories, only to remove them from the path string.